# How to use (or open) args in python when some inputs are named and others are not?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, list-comprehension, args

I want to make a few user using create_superuser method. I am currently doing this:

```
CustomUser.objects.create_superuser(
    'amin@gmail.com',
    'password',
    first_name='Amin',
    )
```

But I want to create more than one user. I did not want to give first_name, I would do this:

```
a=[['user1@gmail.com', 'pass'], ['user2@gmail.com', 'pass'],..., ['user100@gmail.com', 'pass'], ]
[CustomUser.objects.create_superuser(*user) for user in a]
```

But in my case, in which I have a third input for which I need to put the name 'first_name', how can I do what I did in above?

Comment: If that's literally all you want to do, drop the for loop. It's not making your code more readable.

Comment: I edited the question and changes it into creating 100 superusers

Comment: Why doesn't this work for encoding your data: `a=[['user1@gmail.com', 'pass'], 
   ['user100@gmail.com', 'pass', 'John'], 
  ]`? Also, you should use a for loop instead of a list comprehension which is used for creating a list, not for its side effects.

Comment: I checked it. It did not work. I did what you said and then did this in django shell to check: ```am=CustomUser.objects.get(email='amin@gmail.com')```  and then ```am.email``` returned 'amin@gmail.com' but ```am.first_name``` returned nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must mix positional and keyword arguments in a loop:

```py
users = [
    (
        ('user1@gmail.com', 'password'),
        dict(),
    ),
    (
        ('amin@gmail.com', 'pass'),
        dict(first_name='Amin'),
    ),
]

for args, kwargs in users:
    CustomUser.objects.create_superuser(*args, **kwargs)
```

Personally I think this looks awful.

Answer (score 2):

Use keyword arguments only:

```
users = [
    dict(
        email='user1@gmail.com',
        password='password',
    ),
    dict(
        email='amin@gmail.com',
        password='pass',
        first_name='Amin',
    ),
]

for user in users:
    CustomUser.objects.create_superuser(**user)
```

Comment: This solves the problem but it is still not the solution to the question of how to use a mix of naming the inputs and not naming them while you need to use for loop. In your solution, you are repeating email and password in each dic while I want it to be ommited.

Comment: Are you hardcoding 100 sets of parameters? Then go back to my suggestion of not using a loop. Are you generating these parameters programmatically? Then you're not going to repeat `email` and `password` 100 times.

Comment: I am hardcoding them once and will use them every time I am makin migrations and migrating

Comment: Then make a function `def make_users(): create_superuser(...); create_superuser(...); ...`